# Can an acrobat dc variable reference more than one field?

Tags: formatting, field, acrobat

I want my form to capture address information for users that have either a US or Canadian mailing address. The form defaults to a US mailing address format. I have a dropdown field 'fCountry' populated with "USA" and "Canada".  If fCountry = "Canada" I want to hide the US address format fields and have Canadian address format fields appear. Is there a way to hide or unhide several fields on a form using the same variable?  There are some similarities between US and Canadian formatted addresses and if I can use those common address elements, I will.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using hierarchical field naming (see Acrobat JavaScript documentation for more details).

Field names can be hierarchically grouped by separating the parts with a period. So, in your case, you would have fields named like `address.us.town` or `address.us.zip` or `address.cdn.city` or `address.cdn.postcode`.

With, for example

```
this.getField("address.us").display = display.hidden ;
this.getField("address.cdn").display = display.visible ;
```

you can hide all fields containing the `address.us` component in their field name and show all fields containing the `address.cdn` component.

FWIW, this approach also allows for partial reset of the form.